# Set number of columns in text-based interface

Tags: output-formatting

Is it possible to set the number of columns in *Mathematica*'s text-based interface? Or disable word wrapping in the text-based interface ?

Specifically, my concern is output from `MatrixForm` and `TableForm`, which wraps output at about 85 columns. It seems as if the values were hardcoded in 1992.

I use the text based interface within an emacs shell buffer.

EDIT: The answer below that I checked green solves this problem in a few tests of commands that give long output, such as MatrixForm.

Comment: Not 1992, Perhaps about five years earlier than that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't use the command line and haven't tried this but I suspect that

```
SetOptions["stdout", PageWidth -> Infinity]
```

may be what you are after.

Comment: +1. It also affects the width of the standard `InputForm` output in the FrontEnd.