# How to make lines not wrapping in text-mode Mathematica?

Tags: kernel, text, kernel-startup, command-line, unix

When running Mathematica from Unix command line, i.e. pure text mode, the lines wrap at about 70 pr 80 characters, creating lots of visual clutter.  How do I set it so that any outputs will not wrap with an `\` or wrap at a customized value?

Comment: Duplicate of [Set number of columns in text-based interface](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55143/27951)